# Specify Button on submit

Tags: jquery

I have an input handler like so:

```
$('.submit-on-enter').keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('input[type=submit][for=' + id + ']').click();
  }
});
```

This is a form with multiple buttons. The issue I'm having is that when the form hits the server, the very first button is there rather than the one that was 'clicked'.  I've verified that the id in the above handler is the expected id.

And to be clear, I'm checking for the existence of the name attribute on the button server side to determine which button was clicked.  The name of the very first button on the page is always there, regardless.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all the buttons set up to submit the same form? If so, that's probably your issue.

Comment: @jack: Why is that my issue when a physical click doesn't result in the same behavior?

Comment: what about using e.preventDefault() to prevent the sending of the original keydown event

Comment: @ITroubs: The original keydown comes from an input[type=text] element.

Comment: @Jack why is that an issue? There are many applications where you need multiple buttons to submit one form with the possebility to distinguishe the actual cliecked button.

Comment: @Fred yes i konw that but when you press the `enter` button then your form will be originally submitted by the first submitbutton in your form unless you catch the keydown event and do prevent that event from further processing

Comment: @ITroubs ok, I see the issue, but not how to prevent it.  e.preventDefault() in the above handler is not fixing the issue, neither is return false.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26559/discussion-between-fred-and-itroubs)

Comment: @jack The browser sends down the name of the first submit button it finds on enter (but not on click).  I understand that, which is why I'm firing the click() event, because I don't want to send down the first button found, but rather, the button whose click() event was fired.

Comment: @ITroubs the keydown event doesn't seem to let you stop the form submit on enter in chrome, switching to keypress did the trick.

Comment: @Fred now that you say it I once had that problem where I wanted to prevent an autocomplete field from submitting the whole form on hitting enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution, note the change in events.  keydown doesn't seem to allow stopping the form submit event in chrome.

```
$('.submit-on-enter').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var name = $('input[type=submit][for=' + id + ']').attr('name');
    $('input[type=submit][for=' + id + ']').click();
  }
});
```